# libc6:armhf issue when running dist-upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

I am running raspbian and when trying to run sudo apt-get dist-upgrade I am getting the following output:

http://pastebin.com/QZsR8MjB

I think that the relevant part is

```
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing libc6:armhf (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

I have tried sudo `apt-get clean` `sudo apt-get autoclean` `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and of course, `sudo apt-get install -f` in pretty much every possible order, but without any luck. All but the first two output the complaint about `libc6:armhf` like shown above.

Could anybody please give me some directions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: is your system architecture `armhf`?

Comment: Well, `readelf -A /proc/self/exe | grep Tag_ABI_VFP_args` returns ` Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers` and according to https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/entry/is_it_armhf_or_armel I'm indeed running armhf. The device is a raspberry pi 2. And it didn't complain about this in the past.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out... the solution was to make a directory by typing

```
mkdir /var/cache/debconf
```

Many thanks to the one who posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219798/debconf-or-perl-error-during-apt-get-install) who also answered the question himself.

Hope this helps anybody.